# inputing road network as nodes and arcs in java

Tags: java, network, road

I want to input a road network as nodes and arcs. Some of the nodes are intersections, others serve to describe the shape of the road. Road network should be modeled as an embedded graph consisting of nodes and arcs.

I want to model the input road network as a graph G with node set N and arc set A, and with the following information:

1. Each node in the set N is a point with geographic coordinates. Each node has references to the incident arcs of the graph.
2. Each arc in A has some importance, representing the type of road (dirt road, ..., highway), and it has references to the two incident nodes.

Please help me with the code in java for doing the same.

Comment: did you have a solution for that?